# KML file google earth to integrate in uiMapkit

Tags: objective-c, kml, compass-geolocation, mapkit

i want to get the latitude and langitude in order to make annotation in mapkit.

i want to run kml file in objective c but nothing happen all are in javascript.

any suggesion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did [a bit of Googling for you](http://developmentseed.org/blog/2010/aug/12/kml-parsing-library-released-apples-ios-platform/).

Grab the [Simple-KML parsing library from GitHub](https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML) and look at the sample project that comes with it and see how it parses out latitude and longitude (which I believe are SimpleKMLPoints?) and then you will be able to make your annotations into MapKit.

Hopefully I set you in the right direction!

Comment: thanks! now i can make annotation using kml files but i have to download kml each time .is there any api of google earth which return kml file in return ?